# make: invalidate object file when dependency is missing

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a situation where I've refactored some code, and moved an include file.

Attempting to build the source tree yields an error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `cmd/dispatcher.h', \
    needed by `/tmp/test/dispatcher/main.o'.  Stop.
```

If I do a `make clean` (which removes the outdated `main.o` file), and then rebuild I get a different error:

```
...src/test/dispatcher/main.cpp:3:28: fatal error: cmd/dispatcher.h: \
    No such file or directory
```

**Question:**

Is there any way to invalidate `main.o` when one of its dependencies is missing?

Comment: I dont think so. But you can tell the makefile to build always in such situatuions with --always-make flag to make

Comment: Is `main.o` no longer needed in your build?

Comment: @SagarSakre I'd like to avoid this - having `main.o` realise a dependency `cmd/dispatcher.h` is missing would cause `main.cpp` to be rebuilt without rebuilding the rest of the world

Comment: @Beta it is required - it is the relationship between `main.o` via `main.cpp` to `cmd/dispatcher.h` which I'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic in `make`. If `main.o` depends on `dispatcher.h`, then it *is* written somewhere.

I suspect your `Makefile` runs `gcc` with the `-MD` or `-MDD` option that creates a dependency file. Usually they are named with a `.d` suffix. These dependencies files are automatically created by `gcc` as Makefile content: `target: dependencies`.

These files are then included into the main `Makefile` to provide the full automagic dependencies.

You should look for these `.d` files and remove them.

Comment: `deps := $(subst $(OBJ_DIR),$(DEP_DIR),$(subst .o,.d,$(OBJECTS)))
-include $(deps)`

Comment: Sorry - pressed enter too soon... My dependencies are automatically generated as follows: `deps := $(subst $(OBJ_DIR),$(DEP_DIR),$(subst .o,.d,$(OBJECTS)))
-include $(deps)`. You're right that the old file is listed in the `.d` file, I guess I'm looking for a way to have that `.d` file invalidated and therefore rebuilt

Comment: @SteveLorimer If your issue is caused by outdated gcc autodependencies the  additional `-MP` option should help you avoid this next time.

Comment: @SteveLorimer You mean that your dependencies are **used** as follows. These lines do use the `.d` dependencies files. They do not generate them. Check that gcc is run with `-MD` option, then delete the offending `.d` file, and run `make`.

Comment: @DidierTrosset apologies, you are of course correct. The dependency generation is with `-MM`: `$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -MM -I. $< > $@`. I will look up `-MP` and `-MD`